# Android socket doesn't listen to some Socket.io emits

Tags: javascript, android, socket.io

I am building an Android (& web) chat application using Socket.io.
When I `io.emit` some *pure string* data, Android listens to it, but it doesn't when I emit some modified string like `SOME_CONST_STRING + msg`.

#### server.js

```js
const SYS = '[알림]';
...
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('join', (name) => {
        names[socket.id] = name;
        let data = {"name": SYS,
                    "message": CONNECTED_MESSAGE_WITH + name,
                    "color": SYS_COLOR};
        io.emit('chat message', data);
        var msg = data["message"];
        io.emit('toast join', msg);
    });
    ...
}
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
mSocket.on("toast join", new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String msg = (String) args[0];
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, msg);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

For `toast join`, when I emit `name` (instead of `msg`) it works.

What's the difference and which side is causing the problem?

Comment: If your server emits an object, such as `msg`, then the client will receive `args[0]` as a `JSONObject`, instead of a `String`. IOW, I think your `Runnable` is throwing due to a class cast exception on the first line. The debugger is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
 let testString = CONNECTED_MESSAGE_WITH + name;
 let data = {"name": SYS,
             "message": testString,
             "color": SYS_COLOR};
```

Debug and see the value of testString.